# Best Picasa gem for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, picasa

Is there any gem for the Picasa API? I've tried to use github.com/morgoth/picasa, but this gem does not support authorized requests.

Comment: http://ruby-picasa.rubyforge.org/?

Comment: Yes, I can use ruby_picasa, but last update for that gem - at 2009/05

Comment: picasa gem supports authentication - check it out

Answer (score 1):

These are my findings about Gems for Picasa in ruby on rails.

https://github.com/pangloss/ruby_picasa

https://github.com/morgoth/picasa

The second one is new and will help you, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If still interested,  you can use http://picasaonrails.googlecode.com/ It allows uploading and album creation

check http://picasaonrails.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/picasa_on_rails/README for use samples

To use it you can install as a plugin or just download http://picasaonrails.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/picasa_on_rails/lib/picasa.rb and http://picasaonrails.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/picasa_on_rails/lib/multipartpost.rb for any ruby (not rails) project

Answer (score 0):

I'm a contributor. I don't know if it's the best, but I use it in production: https://github.com/mkraft/PicasaWebAlbums